# VirtualBox, mounting Ubuntu 12.04 on windows 7

Tags: virtualization

I am trying to start Ubuntu 64x with VM on Windows 7. I get this message when I start the system:

[image]

Everything seems to be ok with the settings. I am using a VDI image.

### What can I try to do for solve the problem?

This is the result when I run 'cat /etc/fstab':

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is normally a problem with your /etc/fstab file. 
Does pressing 's' let you go into the operating system? If so you could paste the output of 'cat /etc/fstab' so we can see if there's a problem.

Also run 'ls -l /' in the terminal and post the results to that. Your /tmp folder could be a symlink, so you could remove it, recreate the directory normally and after a restart should work fine.

If you are only just installing the operating system now, I would recommend scrapping this installation and install 14.04.

Comment: you just want to see what is in there, so type 'cat /etc/fstab'. '/etc/fstab' makes it try to run the file

Comment: I updated the instructions as well

Comment: There's a space, 'cat /etc/fstab'

Comment: Again don't leave out the space

Comment: I tried the both! Look up the print screen that I add to my question.

Comment: ... you left out a space again

Answer (score 0):

Try updating and upgrading your system.

Press 'M' and then run these commands one at a time.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot your system.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1724209

Comment: I got: sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 0, sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 0, sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting, sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin